# Most effective search algorithm to find multiple incorrect values in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, evaluation, processing-efficiency

Suppose the next array:

```
int a[] = new int[15];
```

Each value is a counter of some days in a specific state in a period in a database.
Example: **Period 1/1/2000 - 1/3/2000 (3 days, not 3 months)**: Number of days in state **XXXXX**.

What I want to do is check if the objects count is correct compared to the objects count on a website. The search itself takes some seconds at best if the website is not loaded.

I had made a very simple test project which compares the values of a with some fixed values on another array and I randomly chose some values to be different, in fact 7 out of 15 were different.

The current algorithm implemented is **binary search**. The output of this piece of code is correct, but the number of searches that would occur on the real application is 144 for the data provided, which is not efficient at all. Is there any other algorithm that I could use to minimize the number of searches (or summary calculations in this example)?

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** The periods can be as large as Sep 1, 2010 - Today, so for the moment searching each day independently is not an option.

*Ask me for explanations if needed.*

```
    a = new int[15];
    b = new int[15];
    searchCount = 0;

    // Fill a and b with some test values
        a[0] = 12;
        a[1] = 13;
        a[2] = 26;
        a[3] = 30;
        a[4] = 6;
        a[5] = 3;
        a[6] = 1;
        a[7] = 2;
        a[8] = 8;
        a[9] = 12;
        a[10] = 19;
        a[11] = 21;
        a[12] = 56;
        a[13] = 100;
        a[14] = 80;

        b[0] = 11;
        b[1] = 9;
        b[2] = 26;
        b[3] = 30;
        b[4] = 8;
        b[5] = 3;
        b[6] = 1;
        b[7] = 5;
        b[8] = 8;
        b[9] = 13;
        b[10] = 19;
        b[11] = 21;
        b[12] = 55;
        b[13] = 99;
        b[14] = 80;
    // Filled.

    void BinarySearch(int start, int end)
    {
        if (AreSumsEqual(start, end))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Values from positions" + start + " to " + end + " are ok");
        }
        else if (start == end)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Value at position " + start + " is not ok");
        }
        else
        {
            int mid = Middle(start, end);
            BinarySearch(start, mid - 1);
            BinarySearch(mid, end);
        }
    }

    int Middle(int start, int end)
    {
        return (int)Math.Ceiling((start + end) / 2.0);
    }

    bool AreSumsEqual(int start, int end)
    {
        bool areEqual = false;
        int sumA = 0;
        int sumB = 0;
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
        {
            sumA += a[i];
            sumB += b[i];
            searchCount += 2; // Each sum calculated is the same as one 
            // website search. This takes the most time in real application, so
            // repeat it as few times as possible.
        }

        return areEqual = (sumA == sumB);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried the binary search provided in .net framework? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch.aspx

Comment: Am I wrong, or does the algorithm mark [1,2,3,4] and [1,1,4,4] as _ok_, but [1,2,3,4] and [2,1,3,5] as _not ok at the fourth position_? And wouldn't it be easier to sum up everything once while at the same time looking for the first difference and return that if the result isn't equal?

Comment: Could you add the test data?

Comment: Added test data. Also: [1,2,3,4] [2,1,3,5] marks positions 0,1,3 as not ok.

Comment: @Calbertoferreira The array is not sorted. Moreover I want to spot all positions with different values. The BS is used to compare multiple rows at once to avoid searching all of them 1 by 1 if possible.

Comment: @Nuffin That would make sense perhaps to save time, I will surely discuss that idea with the team.

Comment: Why not just `for i = 0 to length do if a[i] != b[i] then print 'wrong '+i`?

Comment: What you want is not really a binary search, you want to compare two arrays the fastest way. Ishtar idea seems fine to me at first glance

Comment: @Ishtar There might be 100s of rows not just 15 and each comparison might take form a few seconds to 1-2 minutes depending on the internet connection, so we want to limit the searching, by comparing large sets of rows.

Comment: I haven't fully understand your problem. But it seems that you can reduce the complexity of AreSumsEqual by using a Binary Indexed Tree.

Comment: @shilk I want to avoid AreSumsEqual as much as possible, not make it faster.

Comment: @Souvlaki Can't you just download the entire array? That should take 1-2 minutes and then you can check all the data in 1 millisecond.

Comment: Downloading the entire array means 15 times: navigation, searching and reading the value from the results. This is the number we are trying to reduce, but as the discussions continue we believe that maybe there's no faster way than this.

Comment: Don't know if I understood correctly. But in a first moment, you can store accumulated sums to provide O(1) range summarization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use binary search here, since you need to check every [start, end] combindation. Also, if you search in both directions with binary search, it is not binary search anyway.

I'd suggest the following solution:

```
// Remove this, if you want all matches
bool found = false;

for (int start = 0; start < a.count; start++)
{
      // Maybe you need end = start + 1, not sure
    for (int end = start; end < a.count; end++)
    {
        if (AreSumsEqual(start, end)
        {
            // Found! Let's break to avoid useless iterations,
            // if we only want one match.
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found)
    {
        break;
    }   
}
```

This runs in O([n(n - 1)] / 2) (if I'm not mistaken) which is O(n²) in the worst case. Since you have to check all all [start, end] combinations, you can't solve this with a smaller order of magnitude.

**EDIT:** This is provided I understood your question.

Comment: We'll evaluate your solution. What I can assure you is that currently stopping the search for either the first correct or first wrong value is not an option.

Comment: OK. then just remove the `break` s and the `found` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
var SearchResults = a.Select((value, index) => a[index] == b[index]);

for (int i=0;i<a.Length;i++)
{
  Debug.WriteLine("Values in position {0} are {1}", i, SearchResults.ToList()[i]);
}
```

As i said in the comments, you just need a simple comparison between each position on two arrays.